# Android App FIPS Compliance on Samsung device equipped with FIPS BoringSSL

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, fips

Samsung device is equipped with the BoringSSL module which is declared to be validated by FIPS 140-2(Refer to https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/certificate/3900). Can we imply that application running on this device and invoke the encryption API using Android Jetpack Security is also FIPS compliant? Seems Android Jetpack security is using Tink, Tink is eventually invoke the security provider from Android system to do the real job, which is the the OpenSSLProvider from Conscrypt by default. Conscrypt depends on BoringSSL for the real encryption and decryption.

Answer (score 0):

There is a key phrase in the link you provided, and that's

> When operated in FIPS mode.

The fact that Samsung devices use the BoringSSL module, and BoringSSL has been FIPS validated at some point, tells you nothing about whether the particular version and build of BoringSSL bundled with Android on recent Samsung Devices has in fact been compiled and is being initialized at runtime in "FIPS mode".

If you cannot find unequivocal official confirmation that this is true for the devices and OS versions you are looking at, your only course of action is to compile and bundle a custom version of the SSL library with your app, following the official vendor guidelines required to produce a FIPS validated build of the library.